# onnxruntime-web fails to find ort-wasm-simd.wasm, doesn't use my /static folder in SvelteKit

Tags: javascript, node.js, webassembly, sveltekit

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: no available backend found. ERR: 
    at t.resolveBackend (backend-impl.js:91:11)
    at async i.create (inference-session-impl.js:175:15)
    at async createSAM (SAM.ts:59:19)
    at async init (http://localhost:5001/src/routes/(app)/app/project/[projectId]/auto-detect/+page.svelte?t=1695723086870:936:9)
```

In the console I see this:

```
Error: Not found: /app/project/MpUQMHCfHANBXyvH/ort-wasm-simd.wasm
```

This is the only place where I'm specifying a path:

```
const session = await InferenceSession.create('/sam_onnx_quantized.onnx')
```

Changing it to an absolute path with `http://localhost:5001/sam_...` didn't make a difference.

I have this file both in my /static folder, and in node_modules/onnx-runtime-web/dist. It should not be looking for the file in the current page's path.

I don't know what happened, this used to work. I had to delete node_modules and package-lock and do `npm install` for a different issue, maybe it broke after that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the basepath for onnx-web wasm files using the *wasmPath* property on the ONNX env object like this:

```
env.wasm.wasmPaths = path/to/wasm/files
```

This feature is documented in the [API Docs](https://onnxruntime.ai/docs/api/js/interfaces/Env.WebAssemblyFlags.html#wasmPaths)

Answer (score 3):

Here's a specific example that worked for me based on André's post:

```
import { env } from 'onnxruntime-web';
env.wasm.wasmPaths = {
  'ort-wasm.wasm': '/public/ort-wasm.wasm',
  'ort-wasm-simd.wasm': '/public/ort-wasm-simd.wasm',
  'ort-wasm-threaded.wasm': '/public/ort-wasm-threaded.wasm',
  // Add other WASM files as needed
};
```